# NullPointException ao inserir elemento em lista

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

No código abaixo está saindo um NullPointException, tentei corrigir sem mudar completamente o código mas não deu certo, alguém tem uma solução simples?

Estou querendo adicionar um produto na lista `List<Produto>produtos` lá na classe Orcamento.

Segue a classe chamada Crud:

```
public class Crud {

    private Produto produto;

    private Orcamento orcamento;

    public void adicionarProduto(){ 
        this.orcamento.getProduto().add(produto);
        produto.setOrcamento(orcamento); 


    }  
}
```

Segue a classe Orcamento

```
import java.util.List;


public class Orcamento {

    private List<Produto>produtos;
    private String descricao;  

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao; 
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProduto() {
        return produtos; 
    }
    public void setProduto(List<Produto> produto) {
        this.produtos = produto;
    }
}
```

Segue a classe Produto

```
public class Produto {

    private String nome;
    private double preco;

    private Orcamento orcamento;

    public Orcamento getOrcamento() {
        return orcamento;
    }
    public void setOrcamento(Orcamento orcamento) {
        this.orcamento = orcamento;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }
    public void setPreco(double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

}
```

Segue o Teste

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Orcamento orcamento = new Orcamento();

        Produto produto = new Produto();
        produto.setNome("Feijao");
        produto.setPreco(6.4);

        Crud ct = new Crud(); 
        ct.adicionarProduto();

        orcamento.getProduto();

    }
}
```

Segue o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Crud.adicionarProduto(Crud.java:8)
at Teste.main(Teste.java:12)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um dos problemas no código é ao tentar adicionar um produto em uma lista não inicializada `produtos` da classe `Orcamento`, para inicializar sua lista você pode fazer assim:

```
private List<Produto>produtos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ainda para esse caso, você poderia otimizar sua classe pois dificilmente você vai adicionar uma lista inteira de Produtos no lugar da antiga, então você poderia trocar seu método `setProduto()` para `addProduto()`. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Orcamento {

    private List<Produto>produtos = new ArrayList<>();
    private String descricao;  

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao; 
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos; 
    }

    public void addProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produtos.add(produto);
    }
}
```

Para adicionar um novo produto, no lugar disso:

```
this.orcamento.getProduto().add(produto);
```

Você põe isso:

```
this.orcamento.addProduto(produto);
```

Encontrei também alguns erros na classe Crud, como por exemplo não inicializar a variável `orcamento`. Você pode fazer isso no construtor da classe ou direto em sua declaração. No exemplo abaixo eu fiz via construtor, sendo assim, lembre-se de passar a variável `orcamento` criada no seu `main` para ele via construtor assim: `Crud ct = new Crud(orcamento);`.

Além disso, você não passa o `produto` para o método `addProduto`. Consertando ficaria assim:

```
class Crud {
    private Orcamento orcamento;

    public Crud(Orcamento orcamento) {
        this.orcamento = orcamento;
    }

    public void adicionarProduto(Produto produto){ 
        this.orcamento.addProduto(produto);
        produto.setOrcamento(orcamento); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Otimizei, mas ainda esta dando nullPointException, acho que é no main... Mas nao estou conseguindo

Comment: Veja a atualização que eu fiz na resposta, por favor.

Comment: okey fiz as alteracos q vc alterou, obrigado Math, mas ao imprimir a lista no main System.out.println(orcamento.getProdutos());   está saidno vazio

Comment: Você pode criar um construtor no Crud() e inicializar a variável orcamento dele assim. Vou atualizar o código

Comment: Pronto! :) ​​​​

Comment: Vlww, muito obrigado. Agora deu Ceto :D